# Change Rectangle Properties on Mouse Event in C# / WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have an array of rectangles generated like so:

```
        int nRec = 3;
        double sizeRec = 30.0;
        Rectangle[,] recArray = new Rectangle[nRec, nRec];

        for (int i = 0; i < nRec; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nRec; j++)
            {
                recArray[i, j] = new Rectangle()
                {
                    Width = sizeRec,
                    Height = sizeRec,
                    Fill = Brushes.Red,
                    Stroke = Brushes.DarkRed,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                };
                // Add to a canvas for example
                recArray[i, j].MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender2, e2) => ClickEvent(sender2, e2, i, j);
                front_canvas.Children.Add(recArray[i, j]);
                Canvas.SetTop(recArray[i, j], sizeRec + sizeRec * i);
                Canvas.SetLeft(recArray[i, j], sizeRec + sizeRec * j);
            }
        }
```

They are populated on a canvas called "front_canvas":

```
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="305" Margin="0,0,-0.333,-13" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="509" Name="front_canvas"/>
```

I would like the properties of a rectangle to change on MouseLeftButtonDown.  For example I would like to change the Fill property to green.  As my code above suggests I thought I might be able to accomplish that with something like:

```
    private void ClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e, int i, int j)
    {
        //Code to change Change rectangle properties:

    }
```

Ideally I'd like to avoid using XAML and would appreciate any guidance the community can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
   private void ClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Rect rect = (Rectangle)sender;
       rect.Fill = Brushes.Green;
   }
```

PS: Avoid capturing local variables in a loop. The variable itself and not the value will be captured.

Comment: Okay thanks.  Your solution works with: `Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)sender;`